# How to change the screen orientation when switching from one scene to another in UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, game-development

I have 4 scenes in my game I need to set scene 1 and scene 3 in landscape mode, scene 2 and scene 4 in portrait mode how can I do this? please help me out... I'm searching for a long time but couldn't find out the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Where should I attach the screen orientation script? Gone through several forums and it suggested me to attach it to the camera of the scene. @Marco Elizando

Comment: Anywhere is ok, But it can be inside the script you use to load scenes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load your scene, you can use

```
 Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
```

The available orientations are in [ScreenOrientation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenOrientation.html).

And you can read more about `Screen.orientation` [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html).

About loading scenes you can use `SceneManager.LoadScene(scenename);`, you can read more [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html).